# Can't load TLS/SSL certificate to FileZilla Server - "no start line" error

Tags: windows, ssl, filezilla

I just created a TLS/SSL certificate (in Windows) with the following `openssl` command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

After this, I tried to load it in the FileZilla server but it gives me an error that says:

> Could not load certificate file: error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line(0)

I already verified that the two certificates (key and crs) don't contain any blank spaces, and don't have ^M at the end of any line. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you have select the certificate file (`cert.pem`) as a *Private key file* and the private key file (`key.pem`) as a *Certificate file*.

It should be:

- Private key file = `key.pem`
- Certificate file = `cert.pem`

---

Also the key have to be generated without a passphrase, otherwise you get

> Could not load key file: error:0907B068:PEM
> routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:bad password read (0)

So you need to add `-nodes` to the `openssl` command-line.

---

Though why do you even use `openssl` to generate the certificate? FileZilla Server interface has *Generate new certificate* wizard.